# Open PDF on another tab after click on button in html

Tags: html, jsp

I want to open pdf on another tab/window after click on button.
I tried to set onclick="winodw.location.href" but it still open in same page/window.
Following is my code.

```
<input type="button" value="Report"  onclick="location.href='showpdf?&name=${Name}'">
```

Any inputs

Comment: Im not sure I follow the simple solution would be to use a <a href="linktopdf" target="_blank"> but it sounds like you want to modal load your PDF into the same window so the user never leaves the page. But then you state you want it in another Tab, a little confusing which one is it?

Comment: @Cam . Yes I want open pdf on another tab/window. Not on same window.

Answer (score 1):

use `target="_blank"`   to open in a new tab

Comment: Thanks for inputs. I am using button tag.

Comment: my previous answer will open in new window

Answer (score 0):

Change your input button for:

```
<input type="button" value="Report"  onclick="window.open('showpdf?&name=${Name}','_blank')">
```

The difference is that "window.open" will open a new window and "window.location.href" will redirect the page.